# get socket from Stream

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sockets, stream

i am using following code to open a stream that sends files to a FTP. what i would need is to get the socket out of this so that i can implement the second code posted here.

```
    self.networkStream = CFBridgingRelease(
                                           CFWriteStreamCreateWithFTPURL(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef) url)
                                           );
    assert(self.networkStream != nil);

    if ([usernameText length] != 0) {
        success = [self.networkStream setProperty:usernameText forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPUserName];
        assert(success);
        success = [self.networkStream setProperty:passwordText forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPPassword];
        assert(success);
    }

    self.networkStream.delegate = self;
    [self.networkStream setProperty:(id)kCFBooleanFalse forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPAttemptPersistentConnection];
    [self.networkStream setProperty:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket];

    [self.networkStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [self.networkStream open];
```

.

```
CFSocketRef cfsock = [sock getCFSocket]; 
CFSocketNativeHandle rawsock = CFSocketGetNative(cfsock); 
int flag = 1; 
int result = setsockopt(rawsock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY,
                    (char *)&flag, sizeof(int)); 
if (result != 0)
    NSLog(@\"Could Not Disable Nagle...\");
else
    NSLog(@\"Nagle Is Disabled.\");
```

second block requires a socket in order to be executed and i only have a stream and dont know how to get the socket out of the stream.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call [`CFWriteStreamCopyProperty()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFWriteStreamRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFWriteStreamCopyProperty) on your write stream and specify [`kCFStreamPropertySocketNativeHandle`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStreamConstants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Stream_Properties) to get a CFDataRef containing the underlying CFSocketNativeHandle. You can then extract the socket with `CFDataGetBytes()`.

```
CFSocketNativeHandle rawsock;
CFDataRef socketData =
  CFWriteStreamCopyProperty((__bridge CFWriteStreamRef)(self.networkstream),
                            kCFStreamPropertySocketNativeHandle);
CFDataGetBytes(socketData,
               CFRangeMake(0, sizeof(CFSocketNativeHandle)),
               (UInt8 *)&rawsock);
CFRelease(socketData);

/* Make use of rawsock */
```

Comment: sorry i am pretty green on this.. could you please make an example? thank you for your help!

Comment: thanks, keep getting "couldnt disable nagle".. any idea why? thanks for your help, really appreciate it..

Comment: Check to see if rawsock > 0. If not, have you opened your network stream before calling CFWriteStreamCopyProperty? The native socket may not be allocated until then.

Comment: 2013-05-02 20:56:35.344 Stockuploader[806:303] 115192560
2013-05-02 20:56:35.344 Stockuploader[806:303] Could Not Disable Nagle...

Comment: i get `Initializing 'CFDataRef *' (aka 'const struct __CFData **') with an expression of type 'CFTypeRef' (aka 'const void *') discards qualifiers` on the second line and `Use of undeclared identifier 'data'` on the third...

Comment: For me CFWriteStreamCopyProperty always return NULL.

Comment: yes.. @bobmoff I ma also getting nil when calling CFWriteStreamCopyProperty . It was working for me yesterday but today it fails.. Any reason??